# Search troubles with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been playing with ES for few days and have a strange behavior when i perform a search query, i am sure i am missing something and has nothing to do with ES issue. I have created a few email address in my database for testing purpose and one of them i need to find is `"feaviera3a3e@veistzvmldsvjio.com"`, somehow when i type `"veistzvmldsvjio.com"` i get the results but when i type

> "veistzvmldsvjio"(with out .com) no results found.

Here is my code:

```
query: {
 "multi_match" : {
       "query"  : "veistzvmldsvjio",
       "fields" : [ "email","name","phone","username" ]
 }
}
```

I guess i am doing something wrong but can't figure out what. Do you have any clue or advise what i am missing here?

Thx

Comment: You're missing `*` at the end. Can be added programaticaly in Your app.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it works:

```
"query_string" : {
                "query":    "*whatever*",
                "fields": [ "email","name","phone","email" ]
              }
            }
```

Comment: Be careful with leading wildcards. Those are very expensive. Depending a bit on your use-case there might be a better solution; or this one is fine especially for small datasets.

Comment: Thanks for advice Xeraa, i am not sure if this is the right way to do, i need to install in administration panel an option where the administrator can find the client by phone, email, name or email. I am not a specialist in ES, but it worked fine when i was doing it on MYSQL, so i take my experience from there.  Is there a better option?

Comment: Search does a lot of work when storing the data (to speed up the search afterwards). You‘ll need to dive deeper into analyzers and how search is different to databases. Otherwise you won‘t really get the full potential out of it

Answer (score 0):

You can check es's analyze,eg:

```
curl --request GET   --url 'http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze?text=feaviera3a3e%40veistzvmldsvjio.com' \
```

result:

```
{
    "tokens": [{
        "token": "feaviera3a3e",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 12,
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position": 0
    }, {
        "token": "veistzvmldsvjio.com",
        "start_offset": 13,
        "end_offset": 32,
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position": 1
    }]
}
```

So,use match query "veistzvmldsvjio",it's no results.

Comment: Thx for the tip, i didn't know i can use the analyze for that, i definitely will try that.